# Postgres: Sort a list of strings that contain numbers

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a list of items for sale that are named by their dimensions, and the dimensions can be a range. Their names generally look like `8`, `10-14`, `10`, but can also have non-numeric characters `97.5in` or just `ABC`. I'm trying to find an easy and efficient way to sort and display items by those dimensions when joined against the definition table that contains the dimensions:

```
SELECT *
FROM inventory i
    JOIN item_definition def ON i.def_id = def.id
ORDER BY def.dimension ASC
```

And get results ordered by dimension in the order of `8, 10, 10-14, 12, 14-20, 93.5in, ABC` instead of `10, 10-14, 12, 14-20, 8, 93.5, ABC`.

The order of `ABC` within the sort doesn't matter as long as it doesn't cause errors. I'm most interested in how to sort `8, 10, 10-14, 12, 14-20`.

Comment: Honestly, you need to rethink your model. Comparing 'ABC', '93in' and '14-20' is a guessing game. For one what are the units for `8, 10, 10-14, 12, 14-20`?

Comment: I know the model isn't idea, but I'm looking for a solution that will work with what I've got right now until we can fix it properly. I'm happy making some assumptions that won't hold up for all the edge cases. If there was some way of ordering by interpreting all the numeric characters at the beginning of the dimension and sorting by that it seems like it could work. Something along the lines of: `TAKEWHILE('[0-9]', def.dimension)::number` if that makes sense.

Comment: You can use an icu [`collation`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html#ICU-CUSTOM-COLLATIONS) to treat numbers as numbers - it will parse the number and use the whole thing as a single token.

Comment: You can fix your model by adding an extra numeric column where you can store the real order you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ICU `collation`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html#ICU-CUSTOM-COLLATIONS) can be configured to sort numbers numerically instead of alphabetically. [Demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WACGKbN3)

```sql
CREATE COLLATION num_ignore_punct (
 provider = icu, 
 deterministic = false, 
 locale = 'und-u-ka-shifted-kn');

create table item_definition
(dimension text collate num_ignore_punct);

insert into item_definition values
(8),(1.5),(1.4),(1),( 10), (0),('10-14'), (12),
('14-20'), ('93.5in'), ('ABC');

select * from item_definition
order by dimension COLLATE num_ignore_punct;
```

| dimension |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 1.4 |
| 1.5 |
| 8 |
| 10 |
| 10-14 |
| 12 |
| 14-20 |
| 93.5in |
| ABC |

```
locale = 'und-u-ka-shifted-kn'
```

- [`und-u`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html#COLLATION-MANAGING-PREDEFINED-ICU-UND-X-ICU) is just undefined, default collation to be used as a base for your custom collation. You could instead use something different, like `de-AT`, which would mean the locale `de` for **DE**utsch (German), `AT` for the  **A**us**T**rian variant
- [`ka-shifted`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html#ICU-COLLATION-SETTINGS-TABLE) makes it skip punctuation and whitespace (except decimal points used to parse the numbers)
- `kn` or `kn-true` introduces the numerical sorting

Comment: Wow, this looks great! What does `locale = 'und-u-ka-shifted-kn'` mean?

Comment: @Kevin It's in the doc linked under `ICU collation` above, [also here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html#ICU-COLLATION-SETTINGS). `kn` or `kn-true` introduces the numerical sorting, `ka-shifted` makes it skip punctuation and whitespace (except decimal points used to parse the numbers). `und-u` is just undefined, default collation, as opposed to stuff like `de-AT`, which would mean the locale `de` for **DE**utsch (German), `AT` for the  **A**us**T**rian variant.

Comment: I did read that doc before asking my question, but it wasn't clear to me what the behavior of the pieces do even after reading the doc. I did some experimenting, and `ka-shifted` seems to break up the field to be sorted by whitespace and punctuation. Values `10-14-1, 10-14-03, 10-14-15` seemed to get sorted in the order I would expect too, based on their numeric values after the non-decimal characters. This is very neat overall!